# How can I change date formats "2022-06-04T00:00:00.000Z" to "1525844100000" for react highcharts

Tags: datetime, charts, highcharts, datetimeoffset, react-highcharts

I've the following date: "2022-06-04T00:00:00.000Z" format, We've need of date calculation for highcharts in this numeric type format "1525844100000" so how can I calculate in react-highcharts

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    ordinal: false,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    Date: false,
    tickInterval: 4  3600  1000,
    minRange: 1  24  3600000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%l %P',
        hour: '%l %P'
    },
    offset: 0,
},

series: [
    {
        "data": [[1.424304e+12, 0.25]],
        color: '#FFA749',
    },
],
```

"highcharts": "^6.1.1",
"react-highcharts": "^16.0.2",

I've given above my charts details

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert `ISO-8601` to `timestamp` format, use `getTime()` JS method.

```
let timestamp = new Date('2022-06-04T00:00:00.000Z').getTime()
// expected output: 1654300800000
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vnLdum1k/